# Can I take my Canadian PPL with flight hours logged in the US?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, canada

I was wondering if I can combine my flight training hours in the US with my Canadian ones if I want to take my PPL in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little excerpt from a Canadian document, as it relates to the conversion of licences back and forth between the two countries.

> The Agreement provides, in pertinent part, that the FAA and TCCA will pursue mutual cooperation in the evaluation and acceptance of each other’s systems and standards in the issuance of certificates and licences.

Keep in mind, this text is for conversion after you already have a full license, but I believe each country recognizes the hours in a log book from the other. Best bet would be to call or email the flight schools in the area you plan on going, and get the official word on it.

Edit: I should have put this here in the first place, but here is the link to the [Conversion agreement between U.S. and Canada](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/general-personnel-usconversion-chapteri-2394.htm#1_0). You will find the snippet that I pasted in the 'Purpose and Scope' section.

Comment: could you provide a link to said "Canadian document"?